# How do I find out if user clicked on button on front end from backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend

So I think I have a simple situation here. I want to know which button my users are clicking even if they don't make it to their destination, so click rate over click-through rate. I want to know if people were turned off by a redirect or not, before they get redirected back. Hopefully that makes sense. So I want to find a way to get the front end js code to communicate with the backend code. So I can either read a notification saying "hey this dude clicked on this link" or of course just add it to a dataset and come up with analytics, but the main thing I want it to do is tell the backend code when someone clicked on a front end button.

Comment: This is commonly known as "AJAX". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an EventListeners to listen event click on your different buttons.
When user click on some button, you can use fetch API or axios to do an Ajax call to notify your back end for this action.